# How to update specific fields of widget in the GUI in tkinter and generate a new output from that?

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter, updating

Let me explain my situation , I am trying to generate a file from user-selected option from a GUI in tkinter ,python. So in my program ,as user hits the submit button or enter a binding key ,the value of that widget is updated and program goes to next function. Now if the user wants to change the values of those fields after sometime ,it is not updating them as the function is not traversing back . I am new to TKinter ,so please help me out how to dynamically update widget fields whenever user changes the values of those fields in GUI. At the end whatever values are present in the corresponding fields ,those should be written to the file .This is my requirement .Could there be a way for this?

I have heard of trace as a solution ,but could trace be added to all the widgets in a program at once ? I mean could all widgets be tracked by trace and update the fields which are changed? If so how to implement that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyqPw.png)

I am adding some fields in GUI and after user submits those options ,if user wants to change those values and submit again ,could there be a way to update those values in final file.?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having.